# Install ExtJS in Oozie EMR

Tags: hadoop, extjs, amazon-emr, oozie

Oozie in EMR is NOT bundled with ExtJs for licensing reasons. Hence, the web console doesn't work out of the box.

What are the steps to install ExtJS in EMR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 0: SSH to master node and change user to root.

```
ssh -i <<key-pair.pem>> ec2-user@<<masternode>>.compute-1.amazonaws.com
sudo su -
```

Step 1. Download ExtJs

```
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/gplextras/misc/ext-2.2.zip
```

Step 2: Copy the ExtJs to /usr/lib/oozie/libext

```
cp ext-2.2.zip /usr/lib/oozie/libext/.
```

Step 3: Execute oozie setup that installs ExtJs to the webapp

```
/usr/lib/oozie/bin/oozie-setup.sh
```

Step 4: Change to ec2-user

```
exit (assuming the earlier login was with ec2-user)
```

Step 5: Stop oozie

```
sudo stop oozie (Make sure that the oozie is stopped)
```

Step 6: Start oozie

```
sudo start oozie (Make sure that the oozie is started)
```

Now, the web UI should be accessible in port 11000.